# when android soft input make your et push up , how can I to make the view visible below et?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext, window-soft-input-mode

I have a edittext and a button which is below the editext in a layout.

layout xml may like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:ems="10" >

    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the layout 's activity in androidmanifast is:

```
      android:name="com....activity.CaptureActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

**so , question is :**

when I click or make focus on edittext , the soft input will automatically push up , and it just blocked/covered my button , I want to make button visible.  how can I make the button up right the soft input keyborad when input coming up.

could someone give me some advise? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one to maintain it

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your EditText and Button in a ScrollView like below

```html
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText/>
    <Button/>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: this method doesn't work. the same as before...

Comment: I'm using it on my app and it's working

Comment: uh.. edittext is just above softinput, and it also covered my button   | . |

Comment: Can you post your current layout?